# Compose object from nested list

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have a generic json generated from an XML.

```json
{
  "contextInfoDTOList": [
    {
      "key": "context_info",
      "list": [
        {
          "key": "composition",
          "list": [
            {
              "key": "parts",
              "list": [
                {
                  "key": "part",
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "list": [
                        {
                          "key": "materials",
                          "list": [
                            {
                              "key": "material",
                              "list": [
                                {
                                  "key": "material_value",
                                  "value": "100"
                                },
                                {
                                  "key": "material_name",
                                  "value": "polyester"
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "key": "part_name",
                          "value": "LINING"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "list": [
                        {
                          "key": "materials",
                          "list": [
                            {
                              "key": "material",
                              "list": [
                                {
                                  "key": "material_value",
                                  "value": "100"
                                },
                                {
                                  "key": "material_name",
                                  "value": "cow leather"
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "key": "part_name",
                          "value": "OUTER SHELL"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": "explanation"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract the information to something like this:

```
COMPOSITION

Lining

100 % polyester

Outer Shell

100 % cow leather
```

I have tried a forEach approach, acceding to the keys (composition, parts, materials...), but it gets so dirty and I cannot get the materials list.

I'm considering about using a reduce to obtain an object, but I don't know how to pass an object and use recursivity through the nested list.

Desired object:

```js
export class ContextInfo {
  composition: Composition;
  explanation: string;
}
export class Composition {
  parts: Part[] = [];
}

export class Part {
  partName: string;
  materials: Material[] = [];
}

export class Material {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty ugly input format you have.  But by continually filtering and finding nodes, we can build your output in a fairly reasonable manner:

```js
const byKey = (target) => ({key}) => key == target

const extract = (res) => res .contextInfoDTOList .filter (byKey ('context_info')) .map (info => ({
  explanation: info .list .find (byKey ('explanation')) .value,
  composition: info .list .find (byKey ('composition')) .list .filter (byKey ('parts')) .map (parts => ({
    parts: parts .list .filter (byKey ('part')) .flatMap (p => p.list .map (q => q.list)) .map (part => ({
      partName: part .find (byKey ('part_name')) .value,
      material: part .find (byKey ('materials')) .list .map (material => ({
        name: material .list .find (byKey ('material_name')) .value,
        value: material .list .find (byKey ('material_value')) .value
      }))
    }))
  }))
}))


const res = {contextInfoDTOList: [{key: "context_info", list: [{key: "composition", list: [{key: "parts", list: [{key: "part", list: [{list: [{key: "materials", list: [{key: "material", list: [{key: "material_value", value: "100"}, {key: "material_name", value: "polyester"}]}]}, {key: "part_name", value: "LINING"}]}, {list: [{key: "materials", list: [{key: "material", list: [{key: "material_value", value: "100"}, {key: "material_name", value: "cow leather"}]}]}, {key: "part_name", value: "OUTER SHELL"}]}]}]}]}, {key: "explanation", value: "foobar"}]}]}

console .log (extract (res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(Note that I had to add a dummy `"value"` to your `"explanation"` node to get it to extract properly.  If we don't do this, we'd get an `undefined` explanation.)

We use the helper `byKey` simply to reduce the noise in the body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's your responsibility, to work with the data...

```js
let contextInfoDTOList = [{ key: "context_info", list: [{ key: "composition", list: [{ key: "parts", list: [{ key: "part", list: [{ list: [{ key: "materials", list: [{ key: "material", list: [{ key: "material_value", value: "100" }, { key: "material_name", value: "polyester" }] }] }, { key: "part_name", value: "LINING" }] }, { list: [{ key: "materials", list: [{ key: "material", list: [{ key: "material_value", value: "100" }, { key: "material_name", value: "cow leather" }] }] }, { key: "part_name", value: "OUTER SHELL" }] }] }] }] }, { key: "explanation" }] }]
function* getAllKeyValue(list = [], path = []) {
    for (let item of list)
        if ("value" in item)
            yield [item, path]
        else
            yield* getAllKeyValue(item.list, path.concat(item.key))
}
for (let [item, _path] of getAllKeyValue(contextInfoDTOList)) {
    console.log(item);
    // Todo: work with the data
}
```

Comment: I think this is a nice approach to finding all the leaf key-value pairs.  But, even though you also match the paths to these nodes, I think it still leaves the large bulk of the work elsewhere.  In other words, it's a nice approach, but maybe more useful for other problems than for this one.  (I'd love to be proven wrong, though.)